# Is RDP session logged on initiating OS PC?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I have a Windows 10 laptop (Machine A) & Windows 11 desktop (Machine B) connected to the same router.

From A, I initiated an RDP Session to B. I map the local drives of A into RDP session and copied some files from B to A.

Is there any record or log of event specifically on Machine A Windows OS (May be in event viewer or somewhere else)  that I did perform this copy operation from B to A?

I find it difficult to interpret host & client here, so I am simply using terminology of initiating machine A and remote machine B

Comment: “Is there any record or log of event specifically on Machine A Windows OS (May be in event viewer or somewhere else) that I did perform this copy operation from B to A?” - There can be if the required event logging is enabled

Comment: Windows has the ability to perform auditioning on file access. Due to the obvious ramifications of such detailed logging, that type of auditing, must be configured. So can Windows log when a file is accessed, copied, and transmitted over RDP….absolutely

Answer (score -1):

This following the only RDP event logged at the client's side,
there is no other. It may still indicate that a copy attempt
was done, successfully or not.
Whether the copy was successful or not is to be searched
on the server.

RDP logged events are thoroughly documented by testing
in the article
[Windows RDP-Related Event Logs: Identification, Tracking, and Investigation](https://ponderthebits.com/2018/02/windows-rdp-related-event-logs-identification-tracking-and-investigation/).

The event that is logged on the client is:

**Event ID**: 1149
**Provider Name**: Microsoft-Windows-Terminal-Services-RemoteConnectionManager
**Description**: User authentication succeeded.

The writer notes that the description is somewhat misleading:

> Despite this seemingly clear-cut description, this event actually DOES NOT indicate a successful user authentication in the sense that many might expect (e.g., successful input and acceptance of a username and password). Instead, “authentication” in this sense is referring to successful network authentication, as in someone successfully executed an RDP network connection to the target machine and it successfully responded and displayed a login window for the next step of entering credentials. For example, if I launched the RDP Desktop Connection program on my computer, input a target IP, and hit enter, it would simply display the target system’s screen and produce an 1149 Event ID indicating I had successfully connected to the target, WELL BEFORE I even entered any credentials.

In other words, the writer says :

> TL;DR: NOT AN AUTHENTICATION. Someone launched an RDP client, specified the target machine (possibly with a username and domain), and hit enter to make a successful network connection to the target. Nothing more, nothing less.

This event only means that the client has successfully
connected to the RDP server over the network, but
does not mean that the client's login was successful.

Comment: -1 the question is about logging a file copy after connecting to RDP, not just connecting to RDP.

Comment: @LPChip: This is the only RDP event logged at the client's side, there is no other. It may still indicate that a copy attempt was done. Whether the copy was successful or not is to be searched on the server. I can't invent what doesn't exist.

Comment: My point is that this last statement should be your answer, not how to find out if someone logged in.

Comment: @LPChip: Added. Now it's up to you to undo your downvote and that of the guy that followed in your action.